# Returning a static .json file in Spring MVC as resource

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I want to return a static .json file from server. Not only, for testing purpose I want to define the json file as a resource file (say data.json) so I can comfortably modify it.

I've already done this, putting data.json in resource directory and specifying a resource mapping with:

```
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

My problem is that when data.json is returned the content-type is `application/octet-stream`, while I want it to be `application/json`. How can I specify this?

And further, in my controller i have some methods returning a string (eg. `home`), that are automatically mapped into jsp via the `InternalResourceViewResolver`:

```
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>
```

How can I do the same thing for .json resources (obviously without the jsp compiling process)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in your web.xml you can add this:

```
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>json</extension>
  <mime-type>application/json</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

I believe that will instruct the web container to apply the application/json mime type to any files served with a .json extension.

Answer (score 2):

Revisiting an older question, just to provide a more up to date answer. The following snippet should be self-explanatory:

```
@RestController
public class JsonController {

@GetMapping(value = "/file", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String defaultQuiz() {
    Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("data.json");
    String json = "";
    try(InputStream stream = resource.getInputStream()) {
        json = StreamUtils.copyToString(stream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        throw new YourCustomRuntimeException(ioe.getMessage(), ioe);
    }
    return json;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I managed with this.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/my-endpoint",
    produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String fetchJson() {
    String json = "";
    try(InputStream stream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/my-static-json.json")) {
        json = StreamUtils.copyToString(stream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        log.error("Couldn't fetch JSON! Error: " +
                ioe.getMessage());
    }
    return json;
}
```

Note: the JSON file is under src/main/resources

Answer (score 0):

You can send response as jSON string from your controller by adding `@ResponseBody` for your requested controller method like :

```
public @ResponseBody String getJsonDetails(){

return object; // object may be your list of object(which will send response as JSON) or simple json string
}
```

And you need to configure it by adding following bean in your spring-context xml file :

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
        <property name="mediaTypes">
         <map>
            <entry key="html" value="text/html"/>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
        </map>
        </property>

        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJacksonJsonView">
                    <property name="prefixJson" value="true"/>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Comment: But I want to return a static file, placed on filesystem. In your solution, if I understood it, i have first to load json file as an object, and then return it, serializing again in json format, but this is a redundant process that i want to avoid since data is already in json format.